# How do I grab text in a HTML tag without getting further embedded tag text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse a list of addresses on a page.  When I get to a tag with text and embedded tags, how do I *only* grab text from the tag without getting text in any further (lower level) embedded text at all?

I use a pTag to go from location to location in the .html page and here's the code I deal with:

Python command line, I type: >>> **pTag.address**

and receive the following portion of page code:

```
<address>
                Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br />
<div class="phone">
                    (123) 456-7890
                </div>
</address>
```

So to grab the phone, I type pTag.address.div.text and can easily get it.  I'd like to get the address text that is not nested in another tag.  I could do a re.compile with edge cases in case there is no phone info but I was hoping for something a tad more elegant.

Basically this is what I want, even better with out the br tags:

```
Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [remove elements](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Removing%20elements) using the `extract` method:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '<html><address>Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br /><div class="phone">(123) 456-7890</div></address></html>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.address.div.extract()
<div class="phone">(123) 456-7890</div>
>>> [e.extract() for e in soup.address.findAll('br')]
[<br />, <br />]
>>> soup.address.text
u'Some street addressCity, State and ZIP'
```

Comment: Awesome -- I think I'll prolly go with this if there isn't an even more magical way of "grabbing the first line of text". :)

Answer (score 1):

This feels like it should be easier to do, but the best I could come up with was:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
>>> html = """
... <html><head></head><body>
... <address>
...                 Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br />
... <div class="phone">
...                     (123) 456-7890
...                 </div>
... </address>
... </body></html>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> tag = soup.find('address')
>>> ' '.join(item for item in tag.contents
...          if isinstance(item, NavigableString)).strip()
u'Some street address City, State and ZIP'
```

**EDIT**

Here's an alternative solution using [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.HTML(html)
>>> tag = tree.xpath('//address')[0]
>>> ' '.join(tag.xpath('./text()')).strip()
'Some street address City, State and ZIP'
```

Comment: I know huh... I was feeling the same way re: "more elegant method must exist" but couldn't think of anything.  This is quite good already tbh, and NavigableStrings is a nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible with **only** BeautifulSoup, rather you can remove the unwanted text(div class="phone" tag content) from the whole text. It can be easily achieved through -

```
s = '<html><address>Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br /><div class="phone">(123) 456-7890</div></address></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
s1 = soup.address.text                 // whole text
s2 = soup.address.div.text             // unwanted text
pos = string.find(s1, s2)
s1 = s1[:pos]                          // removing unwanted text
print s1
```

Comment: Yeah I was hoping not to set up multiple strings but thanks for the super quick response!

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in trying PyQuery, here's another way to do it:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery
s = '<html><address>Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br /><div class="phone">(123) 456-7890</div></address></html>'
d = pyquery.PyQuery(s)
print d('address').text()
# 'Some street address City, State and ZIP (123) 456-7890'
print d('address').remove('*').text()
# 'Some street address City, State and ZIP'
```

This removes all child elements from address before extracting the text content.

Comment: This is kinda cool and a lot more elegant actually, though it does require another library...

Answer (score 0):

With regex, it's fast and a complete exctraction is possible with ease:

```
import re

ss = '''a line
another line
<address>
    Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br />
    <div class="phone">
        (123) 456-7890
    </div>
    <glomo>
        Hello glomo
    </glomo>
</address>
end of text'''


def analyze(ss,tag,regx = re.compile('<([^ ]+)([^>]*)>(.*?)</\\1>',re.DOTALL)):
    extract = re.search('<(%s)[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>' % tag,ss,re.DOTALL).group(2)
    li = []
    def trt(m):
        li.append((m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3).strip(' \t\r\n')))
    li.append(('','',regx.sub(trt,extract).strip('\r\n\t ')))
    return li

resu = analyze(ss,'address')
for el in  resu:
    print el

print
print resu[-1][2]
```

result

```
('div', ' class="phone"', '(123) 456-7890')
('glomo', '', 'Hello glomo')
('', '', 'Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br />')

Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br />
```

Or puting the results in a dictionary:

```
def analyze(ss,tag,regx = re.compile('<([^ ]+)([^>]*)>(.*?)</\\1>',re.DOTALL)):
    extract = re.search('<(%s)[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>' % tag,ss,re.DOTALL).group(2)
    di = {}
    def trt(m):
        di[m.group(1)] = (m.group(2),m.group(3).strip(' \t\r\n'))
    di[''] = ('',regx.sub(trt,extract).strip('\r\n\t '))
    return di

disu = analyze(ss,'address')
print "disu[''] ==",disu['']
print "disu['div'] ==",disu['div']
print (disu[x][1] for x in disu if 'phone' in disu[x][0]).next()
```

result

```
disu[''] == ('', 'Some street address<br />City, State and ZIP<br />')
disu['div'] == (' class="phone"', '(123) 456-7890')
(123) 456-7890
```

The functions return nothing (or rather it returns None) then `regx.sub(trt,extract)` replaces tags founs in extract with `""`, it remains only the text in the tag examined.

Comment: Yeah I considered different approaches, especially with a dictionary (since I could just save the entire dictionary at the end) -- I guess I was hoping BeautifulSoup would've provided an elegant, 3-4 line solution.

Comment: @binarysolo Note that ``re`` is built-in and faster than _BeautifulSoup_ and very faster than _lxml_

Comment: Yeah I realize that -- I guess I was going for simple code elegance over speed (since I work in an environment that prefers that) and as noted I'm basically avoiding re.compile just for that.

I understand that BeautifulSoup and lxml are both a bit slow and clunky... just the nature of the beast.